# I'm not sure how to deal with this answer

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205446/contra-konami-code-not-working) was self-answered once the OP figured out what the problem was, however, the solution was pretty much "oh, whoops, I just mucked it up".

> made it work, it turns out my controller pressed maybe both up and left when i pressed up, which made the code not work but i've found a way!

While yes, it answers the question, specifically the OP's problem, it's a terrible answer. What should we do with it?

Answer (score 6):

Downvote the answer and move on.

It's a bad answer, and the question isn't great, (I downvoted it. Whether you do so is on you.) but it *does* have a good answer that Makes The Internet Better. So upvote the good answer, downvote the bad answer, and don't worry about it beyond that.

Comment: Good Answers - making the Internet a better place since 2008

Answer (score 4):

If it answers the questions, but you think it's a terrible answer, then just downvote it. Downvoting is the proper course to take when dealing with low-quality answers.